# Changing the bash =~ operator to a sh compatible argument

Tags: regex, bash, grep, sh, glob

So i am running a bash script in coreos and thus I do not have /bin/bash however I do have /bin/sh.  Now sh has been fine until I was using someone elses bash script and they have the following line.

```
 if [[ "$file" =~ ^https?:// ]]; then
```

and my os complained with `sh: =~: unknown operand` now i assume this mean that the `~=` opeator is not compatible with sh but there has to be some other way to do this form looking on SO I discovered that `~=` is sometype of regular expressions operator.  My question is this then can I replace `~=` with something?  Note: I have grep on my machine.

Comment: Create a function named regex with [Inian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50706715/3776858) and then use `if regex "$file" '^https?://'; then`.

Comment: all these solutions are working I believe I ended up using @glen jackmas 's just because it was most compact and was the first one I used but thanks all +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call out to `expr` which does basic regex matching:

```
if expr match "$file" 'https\?://'; then
```

The pattern is implicitly anchored to the start of the string.

Answer (score 7):

> I have `grep` on my machine

Going by the above line, you could write a simple conditional using an if statement as

```
if echo "$file" | grep -Eq "^https?://"; then
    printf 'regex matches\n'
fi
```

The regex match in `grep` uses ERE (Extended Regular Expressions) which is available in any [POSIX compliant `grep`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1P/grep/) that you have installed. The `-q` just suppresses the normal stdout printed but just returns an exit code to know if the match was successful.

Even if some package of `grep` you have doesn't have `-E` allowed, just use the basic regular expressions support, but deprive `?` of its special value and pass it literally

```
if echo "$file" | grep -q "^https\?://"; then
```

Answer (score 4):

You could rewrite this as a `case` command:

```
case "$file" in
    http://* | https://* )
        # ...
        ;;
esac
```